# Many of my python modules accept the same input arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am working on a python project where I am making many different files that are meant to be called from the command line, and using argparse. There are many recurring input args that are shared with most (but not all) of the modules. At the moment, my modules have a main that looks like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--db', dest='database', action='store', required=True,
                        choices=['test_db', 'production'], help='Choose which database to use.')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--analysis-date', dest='analysis_date', action='store', required=True,
                        help='Date to analyze, format: MM-DD-YYYY')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--skip-data', dest='skip_data', action='store_true',
                        required=False, help='Skip all downloads and parsing.')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    call_some_function(args)
```

That works great for this one module, but I also have ~10 more modules, which take in many of the same input arguments. (keeping in mind that there aren't any inputs shared by every single module)

My question: Instead of having to define these arguments in every main, is there a pythonic way to define them all once, and then call them from each `main` when needed?

I could have one python file with a bunch of if statements, ie:

```
def create_parser(db=False, analysis_date=False, skip_data=False):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    if db:
        parser.add_argument('--db', dest='database', action='store', required=True,
                        choices=['test_db', 'production'], help='Choose which database to use.')
    if analysis_date:    
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--analysis-date', dest='analysis_date', action='store', required=True,
                        help='Date to analyze, format: MM-DD-YYYY')
    if skip_data:
        parser.add_argument('-s', '--skip-data', dest='skip_data', action='store_true',
                        required=False, help='Skip all downloads and parsing.')
    return parser
```

But this seems like a messy way to do it.

Comment: Honestly I don't think your `create_parser` factory function is messy, considering the problem. It's probably the most DRY way to do this

Comment: I agree with @ParkerD. Perhaps I would wrap everything in a config object though if you have many arguments like `def create_parser(config):`.

Comment: `argparse` provides a `parents` mechanism - you define one or more parsers, and it copies their Actions to the child.  The 'copy' is by reference.  But writing your own utility function(s) is just as good an idea.  `ipython` populates its parser from `config` files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a Class and handle whit it all arguments to prevent spaghetti code.
Also, you can pass a "config" tuple, where you have the name of the arguments that you need.

```py
import argparse

class Argument:
    def __init__(self, long_flag=None, dest=None, action=None, required=False):
        self.long_flag = long_flag
        self.optional_arguments = {
            'dest': dest,
            'action': action,
            'required': required,
        }

def create_parser(*config):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Each new argument requires only one new line, DRY!
    arguments_dictionary = {
        '--db': Argument(None, 'database', 'store' , True),
        '-a': Argument('--analysis-date', 'database', 'store', True),
    }

    for argument in config:
        config_instance = arguments_dictionary[argument]

        positional_arguments = [argument]
        if config_instance.long_flag:
            positional_arguments.append(config_instance.long_flag)

        parser.add_argument(*positional_arguments, **config_instance.optional_arguments)

    return parser

parser = create_parser('--db', '-a')
```